# How to pass variable as column value in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

How to pass a variable as a column value in MongoDB:

```
var my_collections = ["test"];
db.Configtable.find({SourceCollection: my_collections},{FilterColumn :1})
```

Getting 0 record

Comment: Can you please elaborate it more with sample docs & required o/p..

Answer (score 2):

Below worked for me

```
db.getCollection(my_collection).find({"FilterColumn":"value"})
```